# Splitting/ Extracting part of Column in a Dataframe - python

Tags: python, dataframe, split, extract

I am trying to split/extract a portion of the "Time" column so it will only show the hours **and** minutes e.g. 18:15 as opposed to 18:15:34.

I've seen alot of examples online that use the .str.split() function with highlighting the colon as the delimiter. But that would split the Time column into three columns: hours, minutes, seconds.

Input Dataframe:

df =

```
Index   Time
0       18:15:21
1       19:15:21
2       20:15:21
3       21:15:21
4       22:15:21
```

Output Dataframe

df =

```
Index   Time
0       18:15
1       19:15
2       20:15
3       21:15
4       22:15
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
df.Time.str.replace(':\d\d$', '')
```

Or reverse-split:

```
df.Time.str.rsplit(':', 1).str[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
df['Time'].apply(lambda x : ':'.join(x.split(':')[0:2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have fair choices here either `replace` , `extract` or `split` with `pandas.series.str`

**First, this is just case based solution..**

Below solution with which does replace the last two number along with `:` across `Time` column.

```
>>> df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.replace(':\d{2}$', '')
>>> df
    Time
0  18:15
1  19:15
2  20:15
3  21:15
4  22:15
```

**Second approach with `str.extract` with regex..**

```
>>> df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.extract('(\d{2}:\d{2})')
>>> df
    Time
0  18:15
1  19:15
2  20:15
3  21:15
4  22:15
```

> - `\d{2} to hold initial two numbers`
> - `:     next to match this immediately after first match`
> - `\d{2} again next two number followed by colon`
> - `$  asserts position at the end of a line`

Comment: It's returning NaN. I wonder if type of that data, being time that is split from a timestamp, needs to be converted to a string before I can replace/ extract it.